next.js 14 fetch Cache missed reason: (auto cache)
I'm building next.js 14 app router project and ran into issue when setting up my api requests. To make external api calls I use next's fetch that has built in caching.
Caching seems to work on simple call:
const getPageData = async () => {
  const pageId = 123;
  return await fetch(`http://myapi.com/page/{pageId}`)
}

But fails when I try to get value from headers().get("pageId") (import { headers } from "next/headers";):
const getPageData = async () => {
  const pageId = headers().get("pageId");
  return await fetch(`http://myapi.com/page/{pageId}`)
}

Second code snippet result in Cache missed reason: (auto cache)
Is there any reason for this behavior? Is there some workaround that does not use 'force-cache'?
Update:
Using one of "Dynamic Functions" (cookies(), headers(), searchParams) switches to dynamic rendering.

By default the use of headers or cookies will opt out caching.
From the docs: "Next.js provides helpful functions you may need when fetching data in Server Components such as cookies and headers. These will cause the route to be dynamically rendered as they rely on request time information"
--
Opting out of Data Caching
fetch requests are not cached if:
The cache: 'no-store' is added to fetch requests.
The revalidate: 0 option is added to individual fetch requests.
The fetch request is inside a Router Handler that uses the POST method.
The fetch request comes after the usage of headers or cookies.
The const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' route segment option is used.
The fetchCache route segment option is configured to skip cache by default.
The fetch request uses Authorization or Cookie headers and there's an uncached request above it in the component tree.
